# Derivation of angular frequency of underdamped harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, oscillators, dissipation

Why is the angular frequency of an underdamped harmonic oscillator given by:$$\omega_1=\omega_0\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}$$

Comment: You better tell what each letter signifies. Generally, you write the damped oscillator differential equation and solve for the case in which the term inside the square root is negative. You then get decaying oscillations, and the oscillations are faster with smaller damping, that's the relation you see.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.